# Error accessing database after migration

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, sql-server-2016

We've an old application made on Classic asp and we're migrating this to a new server.

until here everything works fine, our problem is when the application needs to access the database, we get the following error:

**"An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error."**

The DSN connection is set up and tested.

Any idea why i'm getting this error?

**UPDATE**

***LOG***

> 2017-11-09 11:22:12 192.168.16.172 GET /testing/
>   |55|80040e4d|[Microsoft][ODBC_SQL_Server_Driver][SQL_Server]Login_failed_for_user_'domain\machine-TEMP$'.
>   80 - 192.168.1.122
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/61.0.3163.100+Safari/537.36
>   - 500 0 0 109

Comment: Enable extended logging in your web.config and post the full error you see. Do this by setting `customErrors`to `off`.

Comment: I've posted the log which i have

Answer (score 1):

You are using the computer account to connect to SQL Server. It currently has no rights to connect.

```
[SQL_Server]Login_failed_for_user_'domain\machine-TEMP$'
```

So, open up SQL Server Management Studio and give it the needed rights.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [domain\machine-TEMP$] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english]
GO
```

After you've done that, open up the properties for the newly created account and give it the needed rights on the database used.

Even better would be altering the App Pool in IIS to use a service account and add that account to your SQL Server.